# How to convert hex to binary in Text mode?

Tags: vimscript

I'm trying to convert hex values to binary.
For example, I have got some text file containing:

```
0.0 010111010  B4
0.1 001001011  A3
...
```

And I'm trying to convert `B4` to `10110100`, and `A3` too.

But I can't find any method. So does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The helpfile [`:h eval-examples`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#eval-examples) contains an example of a `number2binary` function:

```
" The function Nr2Bin() returns the binary string representation of a number.
func Nr2Bin(nr)
  let n = a:nr
  let r = ""
  while n
    let r = '01'[n % 2] . r
    let n = n / 2
  endwhile
  return r
endfunc
```

Copy that example to your .vimrc and after restarting your vim, you can do `:echo Nr2Bin(0xB4)` and it will output 10110100.

When writing (e.g. in insert mode) you can then, press `<C-R>=Nr2Bin(0xA3)` and the result will be inserted into your buffer.